# Add an extra option "All" in my dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a dropdown list in Asp.net where I am extracting data directly to the dropdown list from SQL server. So apart from all the data that has been extracted to the dropdown list I want to put one more option "All" in my dropdown list. How could I do that?

Below there is the code for the dropdown list:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
            con.Open();
            string s = "IPAddress";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(s, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            DropDownList5.DataTextField = "IPAddress";
            DropDownList5.DataValueField = "IPAddress";
            DropDownList5.DataSource = ds;
            DropDownList5.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible way:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack){
        con.Open();
        string s = "IPAddress";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(s, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        DropDownList5.DataTextField = "IPAddress";
        DropDownList5.DataValueField = "IPAddress";
        DropDownList5.DataSource = ds;
        DropDownList5.DataBind();
        con.Close();
        DropDownList5.Items.Insert(0, "<-- All-->"); //add this line
    }
```

Insert zero will add it at top of your dropdown.

Cheers,